# what is wrong with this using generic implicit operator?

Tags: c#, builder-pattern

if I use  implicit operator in non generic builder class every thing is ok:

```
 public class ReligionBuilder
{
    private Religion _religion;

    public ReligionBuilder()
    {
        _religion = new Religion(){//some codes}

    }

    public ReligionBuilder AddToRepository()
    {
        Repository<Religion>.Add(_religion);
        return this;
    }
    public Religion Build()
    {
        return _religion;
    }

    public static implicit operator Religion(ReligionBuilder _builder)
    {
        return _builder.Build();

    }
}
```

I can use it :

```
 Religion religion=new ReligionBuilder().AddToRepository();
```

but if this operator is in generic class something is wrong:

```
 public abstract class DataTestBuilderBase<T> : IDataTestBuilder<T>
{
    protected T TestData { get; set; }

    public virtual T Build()
    {
        return TestData;
    }

    public abstract IDataTestBuilder<T> AddToRepository();
    public abstract IDataTestBuilder<T> WithDefault();

    public static implicit operator T(DataTestBuilderBase<T> builder)
    {
        return builder.Build();
    }
}


 public class PersonDataTestBuilder : DataTestBuilderBase<Person>
{
    private Person _person;

    public PersonDataTestBuilder()
    {
        //some codes
    }
    public override IDataTestBuilder<Person> AddToRepository()
    {
       //some codes
        return this;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
 PersonDataTestBuilder _testBuilder = new PersonDataTestBuilder();
        Person person = _testBuilder.AddToRepository();
```

the error is :cannot convert IDataTestBuilder to Person

what is the problem?

Comment: Just a side note, but we also started with our own implement Builders but we ended up using http://nbuilder.org/ It's really nice and has a lot of features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddToRepository` returns just `IDataTestBuilder<Person>` (in terms of the compile-time return type) - and there's no implicit conversion from *that* to `Person`. If you change the return type of the abstract method to `DataTestBuilderBase<T>` then it should work - although frankly I wouldn't want to use that implicit conversion anyway. I'm generally pretty cautious about providing implicit conversions - they can often make the code less clear, as I believe they do here.

Should you really be providing `AddToRepository` on a *builder* anyway? It feels like an inappropriate action for a builder - I would expect:

```
Person person = new PersonBuilder { /* properties */ }
                     .Build()
                     .AddToRepository();
```

EDIT: Just to show what I mean about changing the return type of `AddToRepository`, here's a short but complete program to demonstrate. It works fine.

```
using System;

public abstract class BuilderBase<T>
{
    public abstract T Build();
    public abstract BuilderBase<T> AddToRepository();

    public static implicit operator T(BuilderBase<T> builder)
    {
        return builder.Build();
    }
}

public class TestBuilder : BuilderBase<string>
{
    public override string Build()
    {
        return "Built by Build()";
    }

    public override BuilderBase<string> AddToRepository()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string x = new TestBuilder().AddToRepository();
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: u r right, it shouldnt be in builder, any way your suggestion didnt work!!

Comment: @Adrakadabra: It really does - see my edit for a short but complete example. It's hard to say what you've done wrong without more details, but the principle should be fine.

Comment: u are right, it worked,my problem was that DataTestBuilderBase<T> was implementing  IDataTestBuilder<T> and that return type wasnt correct

Comment: is there any way to have the interface or not?

Comment: @Adrakadabra: No, you can't specify conversions from interfaces.